# TinyMCE 3.5 unwanted element repeat on [return] key

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, silverstripe

I've added an extra button to the TinyMCE editor that simply puts this into the body:

```
<div class="foo">Hello world</div>
```

Clicking on the end of *Hello world* and pressing **return** duplicates the whole div, inside the div.

```
<div class="foo">Hello world<div class="foo">Hello world</div></div>
```

**Half-solution**

By configuring these two options below, the custom  element is not duplicated anymore, but now the issue arises that you need to press *shift + enter* to jump out of any element (h1, address, p etc) which is not preferred in this scenario.

```
force_br_newlines: true,
forced_root_block: ''
```

How can I make TinyMCE stop repeating my custom element on **return key** while conserving the default 

on return key

 behaviour?

Comment: Did you able to solve this issue? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: @Stanly No, I gave up. I believe TinyMCE4 has less of these issues